# PAGMO/PYGMO: Anyone understand the options for Corana’s Simulated Annealing?

Tags: python, minimization, simulated-annealing

I'm using the PYGMO package to solve some nasty non-linear minimization problems, and am very interested in using their simulated_annealing algorithm, however it has a lot of hyper-parameters for which I don't really have any good intuition. These include:

`Ts (float) – starting temperature
 Tf (float) – final temperature
 n_T_adj (int) – number of temperature adjustments in the annealing schedule
 n_range_adj (int) – number of adjustments of the search range performed at a constant temperature
 bin_size (int) – number of mutations that are used to compute the acceptance rate
 start_range (float) – starting range for mutating the decision vector`

Let's say I have a 4 dimensional geometric registration (homography) problem with variables and search ranges:

`x1: [-10,10] (a shift in x)
 x2: [10,30]  (a shift in y)
 x3: [-45,0]  (rotation angle)
 x4: [0.5,2]  (scaling/magnification factor)`

And the cost function for a random (bad) choice of values is 50. A good value is around zero.

I understand that `Ts` and `Tf` are for the Metropolis acceptance criterion of new solutions. That means `Ts` should be about the expected size of the initial changes in the cost function, and `Tf` small enough that no more changes are expected.

In Corana's paper, there are many hyperparameters listed that make sense: `N_s` is the number of evaluation cycles before changing step sizes, `N_T` are the number of step-size changes before changing the temperature, and `r_T` is the factor by which the temp is reduced each time. However, I can't figure out how these correlate to pygmo's parameters of `n_T_adj`, `n_range_adj`, `bin_size`, and `start_range`.

I'm really curious if anyone can explain how pygmo's hyperparameters are used, and how they relate to the original paper by Corana et al?

Answer (score 0):

Gonna answer my own question here. I climbed into the actual .cpp code and found the answers.

In Corana's method, you select how many total iterations `N` of annealing you want. Then the minimization is a nested series of loops where you vary the step sizes, number of step-size adjustments, and temperature values at user-defined intervals. In PAGMO, they changed this so you explicitly specify how many times you will do these. Those are the `n_*` parameters and `bin_size.` I don't think `bin_size` is a good name here, because it isn't actually a size. It is the number of steps taken through a bin range, such that `N=n_T_adj * n_range_adj * bin_range`. I think just calling it `n_bins` or `n_bins_adj` makes more sense. Every `bin_size` function evaluations, the stepsize is modified (see below for limits).

In Corana's method you specify the multiplicative factor to decrease the temperature each time it is needed; it could be that you reach the minimum temp before running out of iterations, or vice versa. In PAGMO, the algorithm automatically computes the temperature-change factor so that you reach `Tf` at the end of the iteration sequence: `r_t=(Tf/Ts)**(1/n_T_adj)`.

The `start_range` is, I think, a bad name for this variable. The stepsize in the alorithm is a fraction between `0` and `start_range` which defines the width of the search bins between the upper and lower bounds for each variable. So if `stepsize=0.5`, `width=0.5*(upper_bound-lower_bound)`. At each iteration, the step size is adjusted based on how many function calls were accepted. If the step size grows larger than `start_range`, it is reset to that value. I think I would call it `step_limit` instead. But there you go.